# Sonarqube integration with MSBuild not working

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, tfsbuild

I have the following scenario with 3 different servers:
- SonarQube server
- TFS server
- TFS build server

I followed ALM Rangers guide to install Sonarqube with the only difference that build agent is in different machine. Manual run of sonar using sonar-runner works on the build machine but when I try to launch a build with msbuid.runner from the build menu in visual studio although project in sonar is created everything is missing such as lines of code, complexity and duplications appearing all as 0. I have tried to see build logs or any other find where I could find any error without luck. Any idea?

Comment: What database did you setup Sonar to use (Embedded/SQL Server)? Can you try checking the logs in <sonar-install-dir>\logs\sonar.log and see if you find any exceptions. You can also enable trace logs using sonar.log.level=TRACE in sonar.properties, and restart the server, this should give you more details in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TFS build summary report as described on page 32 of the ALM Rangers guide, in particular that the build succeed and the "SonarQube Analysis Summary" section exists. If it does then it means the MSBuild.Runner integration pieces have been executed so it's likely the setup of the agent machine is correct.

There should not be any errors or warnings in the build summary report that relate to SonarQube (although there may be other warnings e.g. from code analysis issues).

There is a "Diagnostics" link at the top of the build summary report that gives detailed information about the execution of the MSBuild.Runner integration pieces, including all of the output from the sonar-runner itself.